# MySql Query optimization help needed with 2 table Join

Tags: mysql

I have **1+ million** records in **Table1** table and 1M in **Table2** table I want all **Table1** table records that are not in  **Table2** table. I used bellow query that works fine for smaller data but takes long time with bigger(millions) data. How i optimize this query for this.

here is the query

```
SELECT s.email 
  FROM Table1 s 
  LEFT 
  JOIN Table2 se 
    ON se.email = s.email 
   AND se.list_id in (0,10) 
 WHERE se.email is null 
   AND s.list_id in (10) 
 ORDER 
    BY s.id asc
```

Comment: As well as SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables, questions about query performance ALWAYS require the EXPLAIN for the given query.

Answer (score 0):

Using NOT EXITS may be faster:

```
SELECT s.email 
FROM Table1 s 
WHERE 
    s.list_id = 10 AND
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT se.email
        FROM Table2 se
        WHERE se.list_id in (0,10) AND se.email = s.email 
    )
ORDER BY s.id asc;
```

Indexes on fields `Table1.email` & `Table2.emal` will increase query performance.

Sorting result can increase query time so `ORDER BY` should be removed if it is not nesesary